# How do you customize the pattern / syntax matching used to colorize text in VS2013?

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2013

I'm currently using F# in Visual Studio v12 / VS2013, and I've hit some limitations with the ability to colorize text with [F# power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/136b942e-9f2c-4c0b-8bac-86d774189cff).

What I'm looking to do is to target some text in an enum like this:

```
type Terrain = 
    | Water = 0
    | Rock  = 1
    | Land  = 2
```

so "Water", "Rock" and "Land" will appear colorized. I can't seem to find an option via the regular routes in Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors menu, so how do you modify how VS2013 matches that text in a F# file?

To ask this question more generally, how does one match a text or syntax pattern, preferably by defining a regex or similar, in the text editor to colorize it?

Comment: Why did you tag this regex?

Comment: It was suggested as a tag and I suspected it might be useful in the context of the conversation.

Comment: You might want to clarify the context in your question.

Comment: I updated my question to try to clarify what I'm looking for.

Comment: I've been going through MSDN reading about color syntax highlighting, starting with [this Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Visual%20Studio%20customize%20color%20syntax%20highlighting).  I have yet to see any mention of regex; I don't think they use it for this purpose.

Comment: I've been digging for an hour, both in my local files in the VS2013 installation and on the internet, and I can't find any mention of using a regex for this either. However, if there is a regex that fits this purpose then I would like to know about it. If there's not I would like to know what alternate methods are available for solving this problem. =) To keep this question most general it's probably appropriate to stick to just the visual studio tag, but I'm hoping a regex will be part of the answer, which is why I tagged it with regex. I'm not particularly attached to the tags either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that Visual F# PowerTools do not currently have an option for colorizing enumeration members specifically, so unless it's in the options, you won't be able to do this.

That said, the Visual F# PowerTools project is an open-source and is [hosted on GitHub](https://github.com/fsprojects/VisualFSharpPowerTools). It uses the [F# Compiler Service](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Compiler.Service/) to parse and understand the F# code. So, you can log this as a feature request on the [F# PowerTools user voice](http://vfpt.uservoice.com/) or even contribute yourself!

Visual F# PowerTools get all the information from the compiler and the compiler certainly knows whether an identifier is an enum member or something else - so it's just a matter of exposing this information to Visual Studio. Definitely no regex happening there :-)

Comment: I must have missed somehow that powertools was on github, thanks for that tip. It's good to hear from one of the masters of F#. If I can figure out how to integrate this feature into the powertools pack then I'll submit a pull request. =)

Comment: Nothing in this comment is meant to take away from what you posted. The specific feature here is **semantic highlighting**, and it would operate as a special asynchronous pass independent of the primary syntax highlighting. Primary syntax highlighting examines raw tokens in isolation for maximum performance while the user is typing. Semantic highlighting operates against the internal representation of the code to provide additional coloring of "meaningful" items, so care must be taken to ensure the feature does not impact overall editor performance.

Comment: @280Z28 You're right, but the background compiler is already doing the type checking pass (to give you type information in the tooltips and auto-completion), so adding the semantic highlighting for enums would not add additional performance overhead, because the background compiler already does this anyway. But yes - the coloring would appear asynchronously a bit later after you open the file.